# Equivalent of absolute value when referring to reciprocals

Tags: absolute-value, ratio

I'm currently unaware of terminology or notation that refers to "some function" of a rational number similarly to how "absolute value" relates to a number.  Let me explain.

If one wants to state that a number $x$ must be between $-a$ and $a$ (for some positive value $a$), one can state that $-a < x < a$.  This can also be stated as $|x| < a$, or "the absolute value of $x$ must be less than $a$."

If one wants to state that a number $x$ must be between $\frac{1}{a}$ and $a$, one can state that $\frac{1}{a} < x < a$.  How can this also be stated in a more compact way, similar to the notation/terminology for the absolute value of a number?  Something like $f(x) < a$, or "the magic ratio function of $x$ must be less than $a$."

(As an additional thought, similarly to how the absolute value can be considered the "distance from zero", this unknown function I am trying to find could be considered the "scaling factor from 1.")

Comment: If $x$ is $>0$ then this is the same as $|\ln x|≤|\ln a|$.  Generally, it's the same as $|\ln |x||≤|\ln |a||$ (I think.  I'd check it for a few values to confirm).

Comment: @lulu The second one is correct for $x > 0$.  However, neither is really "more compact" than the original statement $\frac{1}{a} < x < a$.  The first one you stated is pretty good, but I'm hoping there's a succinct/designated function $f$ that gets the job done such that it can be written as $f(x) < a$.

Comment: Assuming $x$ and $a$ are both greater than zero, so far it seems that the most viable option is @lulu's or max$(\frac{1}{x},x) < a$ .

Comment: I don't believe there is such a function in standard use.  Even if there is one out there, it won't help since, as nobody as familiar with it, you'd have to define it in context.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is between $a$ and $b$, then

$a<x<b \implies \frac{a+b}{2}-\frac{b-a}{2}<x<\frac{a+b}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}$
$\implies -\frac{b-a}{2}<x-\frac{a+b}{2}<\frac{b-a}{2}$

Therefore
$$\bigg|x-\frac{a+b}{2}\bigg|<\frac{b-a}{2}$$

Comment: Although interesting and certainly true, this is certainly not "more compact" than $a < x < b$ (or, rather, $\frac{1}{a} < x < a$).